# How can i decrease the specific UITableViewcell height in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview

My requirements is i'm displaying the 7 lines of data in cell Using 7 labels.But some times the data is changes like 6 r 5 lines,On that time i need to decrease the cell size depends on number of lines.I used below code but but app is crashing when End Updates method executes.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
rowHeight = 180;
return rowHeight;}
```

and in cellForRowAtIndexPath method i write the code as

```
    rowHeight = 140;
    [tableView beginUpdates];
   [tableView endUpdates];
```

But my app is crashing when try to execute the endUpdates method..

Comment: Have you got a crash log? I can't seem to reproduce the problem ...

Comment: Why are you doing `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`? Just add a check in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and return correct height.

Comment: What error is the crash printing?

Comment: Mar0ux is right. Why are you doing beingUpdates and endUpdates?